# Json data in High chart

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, highcharts

iam using column high chart to display some data.iam using ajax call to return json data

```
[{"department":"DESIGNING","Present":8,"Total":44},{"department":"SEO","Present":0,"Total":1},{"department":"COORDINATION","Present":1,"Total":2}]
```

i created a high chart with hard coded values as follows

```
$(function () {
    function visitorData(data) {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Attendance Today'
            },
            subtitle: {                
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Designing',
                    'SEO',
                    'CO-Ordinator'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'No.of Employees'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Present',
                data: [5, 10, 15]

            }, {
                name: 'Total',
                data: [20, 30, 40]

            }]
        });        
    }   
});
```

now i want to dynamically include that json data to high chart rather than just hard coding..how can i accomplish that?

Comment: You need to getJSOn and parse to achieve correct form of data.

Answer (score 0):

First you would create an object that represents the data being sent back:

**Model**

```
public class AnObject
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int Present { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public List<AnObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would create an action that returned the populated `MyData` object as json.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var myData = new MyData();

    myData.MyObjects = // populated from a db

    return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You would then call your action via javascript or jQuery, and pass the result to your `visitorData` function

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var aUrl = '@Url.Action("GetData")';

$.getJSON(aUrl, {}, 
  function (data) {
                    visitorData(data);
 });
```

Comment: how can i supply data to both 'x-axis' and 'series'..now im just hard coding the data

Comment: @AfterGlow You could take the same approach as described, just create those objects instead. As the data is returned as json, set them as variables from the getJson result instead.

Comment: the model is in which language? javascript?

Comment: @ShiJieTio The model server-side is c# and when it gets to the client it is json.